# Bank accounts cannot be accessed without a customer ID or account ID

Tags: laravel-4, stripe-payments

I am trying to Verify my stripe account to provide ACH payment and some how stripe banckaccount function doesn't work

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($cust->id);
$bank3 = \Stripe\BankAccount::retrieve($customer->default_source);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong endpoint.  You're looking for the [Retrieve a Customer Source](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_retrieve_bank_account) endpoint.  Once you follow those steps, you can verify the account as described in the [ACH Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts).